# How to add property to object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I've a data like this.

```js
const arr = [
  {name:'john'},
  {name:'jeff'},
  {name:'bob'},
  {name:'peter'},
]

arr.forEach((v,i,a)=>{
  console.log(v)
})
```

And I want to transfer to

`arr = [{id:1,name:john},{id:2,name:jeff},{id:3,name:bob},{id:4,name:peter}]`

I want to add id to every object in array.

How to solves this, Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of [`forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {name:'john'},
  {name:'jeff'},
  {name:'bob'},
  {name:'peter'},
]

arr.forEach((v,i,a)=>{
  v.id = i + 1
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **:**

```js
const arr = [
  {name:'john'},
  {name:'jeff'},
  {name:'bob'},
  {name:'peter'},
];

const res = arr.map((obj, index) => {
   return {
     ...obj,
     id: index + 1
   }
});

console.log(res);
```